# Principal and General Argument product/division relations

Tags: complex-numbers

In books we have seen that $\arg{zw} = \arg{z} + \arg{w}$ (z and w are complex numbers), is here the arg referred to the **general argument** not concerning the principal one only ? So for principal argument it would be $\def\Arg{\operatorname{Arg}} \Arg{z} + \Arg{w} \pm 2\pi = \Arg{zw}$ ? Likewise for divison we would have $\arg\frac{z}{w} = \arg{z} - \arg{w}$ and $\Arg\frac{z}{w} = \Arg{z} - \Arg{w} \pm 2\pi$ ?

Comment: The equation refers to the general argument and is based on the [trigonometry angle sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sum_and_difference_formulas) around $\cos(a+b)$ and $\sin(a+b)$.  That is, consider what happens when you multiply $$r_1e^{i\theta_1} = r_1[\cos(\theta_1 + i \sin(\theta_1)] ~~\text{by}~~ r_2e^{i\theta_2} = r_2[\cos(\theta_2 + i \sin(\theta_2)].$$

Comment: Thanks understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $\textrm{arg}zw=\textrm{arg}z+\textrm{arg}w$ is referred to the general argument, and the reason is the following: let $z=\vert z\vert e^{i\textrm{arg}z}$ and $w=\vert w\vert e^{i\textrm{arg}w}$. Then:
$$zw=\vert z\vert \vert w\vert e^{i\textrm{arg}z+i\textrm{arg}w}=zw=\vert z\vert \vert w\vert e^{i(\textrm{arg}z+\textrm{arg}w)}$$
On the other hand, the principal argument is defined in $(-\pi,\pi]$ (or in $[0,2\pi$), it depends on the author). So if you want to calculate $\textrm{Arg}zw$, by the first formula you obtain an argument in the interval $(-2\pi,2\pi]$, and usually you will need to add or to substract $2\pi$ to return to the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

The [complex argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Identities) is an [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class#Definition_and_notation), and is generally written as $\theta \mod 2\pi$, although other notations are also used, such as $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ at Wikipedia.